# JRuby insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: rubygems, jruby, java

I have successfully installed JRuby `9.0.5.0` on an Ubuntu Server (1 GB Memory / 30 GB Disk / NYC2 - Ubuntu 14.04.4 x64). On command prompt when I try to install  some gems. For example bundler

```
gem install bundle
```

It returns insufficient memory error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00, 65536, 1) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 65536 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

How can I increase the memory settings in order to install the required gems?

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you increase head the Java way prefixed with -J ... e.g. **-J-Xmx624M**

that being said JRuby (<= 9.0.5 at least) sets a 500MB cap automatically and this seems to be related to allocating native memory. hard to tell whats going on exactly, maybe if there's other processes running there's simply not enough memory for JRuby to boot and load RGs (on `gem install ...`)